# EJS characters <% causes 404 even when commented out

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

So I have a webpage thats being loaded with EJS. Work's fine cool. Now I would like to pass some information to the client via ejs using '<%- variable %>.

Example :
Server

```
router.get('/redirect',
    async function(req,res,next){
        try{  
            enterprise = await Enterprise.CreateEnterprise(req.query.enterpriseToken, signupUrl.data.name)
            let enterpriseName = enterprise.data.name
            //let namesubstring = enterpriseName.substring(12,22)
            //console.log(enterpriseName)
            //enterpriseObject['name'] = namesubstring;
            console.log('render')
            res.render('dashboard',{response: enterpriseName})
        }catch(error)
        {
            console.log('Made it to error handling ')
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
)
```

Client:

```
<script>
    console.log('<%- response %>')
<script>
```

Make sense right. It should work but i'm getting a 404 when i actually try to load the page. I automatically stop getting the 404 after I remove the `<%-` from the EJS file. I'm not understanding why these 3 characters are making the webpage break and throw 404. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you handling errors? if so check it doesn't blindly just show 404, what is the value of `data`?

Comment: also note `// console.log('<%- response %>')` wont prevent the `<%- %>` part running

Comment: We need much more context here.  What is the value of `response` and what exactly  does that expand to?  Without only this amount of context, there's no way for us to see how that results in a 404.  Please show much more debugging info and context. 
 Perhaps you're getting an error from `res.render()` that you need to log to see what's happening?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you for clearing that up. After trying to debug I noticed that it made no difference if it was commented out.

Comment: @jfriend00 So i edited my question to include more of my server functionality so you can see what's happening. When testing and debugging I found that It doesn't make a difference whether or not I was passing data to the client  just <%- %> in my ejs file is enough to cause the 404 . When <%- response %> is not null it's supposed to return a value that contains a string such "enterprise/LCO34r9

Comment: Well, you need to break it down to sub-sections of code and figure out which part of the code is leading to the error.  If you only do this in your request handler (all other code in the request handler commented out) `res.render('dashboard',{response: "hi just me"})`, does that work?  This will test if your basic EJS system is working or if the problem is in your EJS template or configuration.

Comment: Also, you need to declare all variables you're using.  Change this: `enterprise = await Enterprise.CreateEnterprise(req.query.enterpriseToken, signupUrl.data.name)` to this `const enterprise = await Enterprise.CreateEnterprise(req.query.enterpriseToken, signupUrl.data.name)`

Comment: If `res.render('dashboard',{response: "hi just me"}),` still has the problem, then there's something wrong with your EJS configuration.  Please shows us the entire `dashboard.ejs` file.  Please show us where it is located in your file system.  Please show us the EJS configuration code that points to the directory where `dashboard.ejs` is located.